# Using python for software automation

Tags: python

My biggest difficulty is finding a tool that I can develop test python.

What could I use?

Comment: the Python ref ? : http://docs.python.org/2/reference/

Answer (score 1):

One common approach is to write your code using the eclipse ide with a pydev plugin

To run tests, write them with the standard unittest module and then run them with the "nose" system